# Incorrect rendering of back button background image

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am setting the background of my back buttons using:

```
UIImage *blueBorder = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_border"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 2, 2)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:blueBorder forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The background image looks like this (this is the @2x):

[image]

Given my insets I am expecting the 2-point blue border to extend around the edge of the button and the remainder to be pink. Instead, I am seeing:

[image]

Note that not only is the background not right, the label in the button is also cropped. It's tricky to see against the blue nav bar but take my word for it. Without the custom background, this does not happen.

Curiously, all is well in the slimmer iPhone-landscape orientation:

[image]

Comment: the background image is supposed to be that small?

Comment: It's just a test. I wanted to see what is going on with the caps so I have a 5x5 image with a 1x1 center which should stretch. Result should be a 2-point border.